# compare a value of a pair with a string

Tags: c++

config is a map within a map:

```
   std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, std::string>> config;
```

I'm trying to parse a configuration file (.ini).

so,

```
config[sectionName] = map<std::string, std::string>>();
config[sectionName][optionKey] = value; //when option and value store a string.
```

Now,

I'm trying to implement this function.
I get errors: one is that "sections == section" and " sections.second == "false" " can't be compared. The error I receive is "error: invalid operands to binary expression".

Could anyone please explain me what is wrong?

```
/*
 * Searches for option's value in section and converts it to a bool if possible.
 *
 * If the value isn't one of the options below or if section/option
 * don't exist the conversion fails.
 *
 * Returns a pair of <bool, bool>
 *  first is set to true if conversion succeeded, false otherwise.
 *  If the conversion succeeds, second is the converted boolean value.
 *  If the conversion fails, it doesn't matter what second is set to.
 *
 *  Converts to true: "true", "yes", "on", "1"
 *  Converts to false: "false", "no", "off", "0"
 *
 */
pair<bool, bool> ConfigParser::getBool(const string& section,
    const string& option) const
{
  for(const auto& sections : config){
    if(sections == section && sections.first != ""){

      if(sections.second == "true" || sections.second == "yes" ||
          sections.second == "on" || sections.second == "1"){

        return pair<bool, bool>(true, true);
      }
      if(sections.second == "false" || sections.second == "no" ||
          sections.second == "off" || sections.second == "0"){

        return pair<bool, bool>(true, false);
      }
    }
  }
  return pair<bool, bool>(false, false);
}
```

Comment: Note that there is [`std::make_pair()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/make_pair). That should relieve you of having to write out the full type of the pair.

Answer (score 2):

Consider your code fragment:

```
for(const auto& sections : config) {
     if(sections == section && sections.first != "") {
```

Here `sections` is a `pair<string, map<string, string>>`, and `section` is a `string`.

Those aren't comparable.

If you just want to look up a section `section`, there are *much* easier ways. for example:

```
pair<bool, bool> ConfigParser::getBool(const string& section,
                                       const string& option) const
{
    auto it = config.find(section);
    if (it == config.end()) { return {false, false}; }

    auto jt = it->second.find(option);
    if (jt == it->second->end()) { return {false, false}; }

    // parse jt->second
    return {true, /* parse result */ };
}
```

Comment: sections is pair<secName, map<optionKey, value>> (all string).

If I want to compare secName with section. I would have to do "sections.first == section"?

Comment: @lv23: Yes, but then the second comparison against `""` seems nonsensical.

Comment: I did that to check if the option of a section has a value or it is empty (""). If it isn't empty check for "true" or "false" values.

Comment: @lv23: I'm saying that a test `X == "foo" && X != ""` is redundant. It's identical to `X == "foo"` (unless the comparison operator does something really weird).

Comment: Oh my bad. I was talking about the value. So I would change it to      (sections.first == section && sections.second.first != "") **not sure if that's possible or would I have to do another FOR EACH to get into the map that's within the other map?

Comment: @lv23: Use the code I posted. I think it does what you mean.

Comment: The thing is I don't understand your code. It probably does the same thing as my code, but if I don't understand it I think I'm just copying an answer.

Comment: @lv23: Hey, you're the one who thought a map of maps of maps of maps was a good idea :-)

Comment: I'm not saying your code is bad hahaha. I was just confused on how maps work, but now I understand my error! (: Thanks!